# why is this method definition syntax accepted in Go?

Tags: go

the code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type unimplementedGreeterServer struct {
}

func (unimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello() string {
    return "hello"
}

func main() {
    s := &unimplementedGreeterServer{}
    ret := s.SayHello()
    fmt.Println(ret)
}
```

the result

```
hello
```

the question :
why the SayHello method has no unimplementedGreeterServer point or unimplementedGreeterServer receiver can run

I think the right will be

```
func (s unimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello2() string {
    return "hello"
}

func (s *unimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello3() string {
    return "hello"
}
```

not

```
func (unimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello() string {
    return "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The receiver itself is optional. If the method does not use the receiver, you can omit it. The declaration:

```
func (unimplementedGreeterServer) SayHello() string {
    return "hello"
}
```

simply defines a method for `unimplementedGreeterServer` that does not use the receiver. It is defined for a value receiver, so it is defined for `unimplementedGreeterServer` and `*unimplementedGreeterServer`.

Comment: any document about it ?

Comment: The go language specification describes the blank receiver: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations